# Is there any other better way to pass parameters to backgroundworker runasync?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am new to **C#** and currently working a project that requires the need for [BackgroundWorkers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx). I found that the BackgroundWorker [RunWorkerAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2(v=vs.110).aspx) simply takes one object as an argument. But there are situations where I will need to pass more than one object into the [RunWorkerAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

What I currently do is to load all the objects into a List then pass them as a single List object which works quite Ok. But my question is, can this be done better or more nicely ? Are there any problems I could encounter with this approach ?

```
List<object> data = new List<object>(3);

List.Add(object1);
List.Add(object2);
List.Add(object3);

bwImportData.RunWorkerAsync(data);

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   List<object> data = e.Arguments a List<object>
   objecttype1 object1 = data[0] as objecttype1;
   objecttype2 object2 = data[0] as objecttype2;
   objecttype3 object2 = data[0] as objecttype3;

   //Do stuff

}
private void RunWorker(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //Do stuff stuff stuff
}
```

Comment: Define them as private properties and then assign values before you start the worker. You can access values in those properties inside the `DoWork ` method.

Comment: @KosalaW he can do that, but it is a kind of wrong approach. Why would he use global variables and make dependency between instance and worker logic when he can simply use wrapper class for the parameters (which is much cleaner).

Comment: It depends on the requirement. Wrapper classes are just another way of doing it. But if you already have a these properties available in your form, why not use them? Most of the times, you have to use these properties in multiple places. But if you don't have them in your form (which is highly unlikely), then it's ok to create a class specifically to pass in as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You may define structure/class for the parameters, create object of that type, fill parameters, and send it as object argument. Later use them directly from the object instead of copying in local variables like in your example `var object1 = data[0] as objecttype1;`.

Comment: Thanks i486 :) I can go away with it with maybe 2 objects but if i have more objects, i will definitely make a class for them.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to wrapping arguments in a class, you can instead use an `Action()` as the parameter and cast the parameter back to `Action` in the `DoWork` handler, like so:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += (sender, args) => ((Action) args.Argument)();

            worker.RunWorkerAsync(new Action(() => test("My String", 12345)));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void test(string s, int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String = {0}, Int = {1}", s, i);
        }
    }
}
```

You can make it a bit easier to read by writing an extension method like so:

```
public static class BackgroundWorkerExt
{
    public static void RunWorkerAsync(this BackgroundWorker worker, Action action)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(action);
    }
}
```

Then the call to RunWorkerAsync() becomes:

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync(() => test("My string", 12345));
```

Comment: @Mathew Thank you very much for this detailed answer. Looks a little Chinese because of my level of experience but i will learn :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any big issues with this approach. In any case you have to combine the arguments into one. Personally, I would prefer the following approach using [tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which needs at least .NET 4.0:

```
bwImportData.RunWorkerAsync(Tuple.Create(object1,object2,object3));
```

and

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
  var data = e.Arguments as Tuple<objecttype1,objecttype2,objecttype3>;
  var object1 = data.Item1;
  var object2 = data.Item2;
  var object2 = data.Item3;

  //Do stuff
}
```

Here you need fewer casts, but this is not such a big deal.

Comment: There is no `new` in the first line before `Tuple.Create()`

Comment: Right, thanks for the hint. Anyway, the answer is outdated. Now, one would use ValueTuple.

Comment: Yes , thank you for the update of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do pass multiple parameters

-Create parameters

```
object obje10 = imageList[i];
object obje11 = i;
object obje12 = product_Name;

object[] parameters = new object[3] { obje10, obje11, obje12};
```

-Send Parameters using RunWorkerAsync

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
```

-Then Get parameters in DoWork method

```
object[] parameters = e.Argument as object[];
List<Image> imgs = parameters[0] as List<Image>;
int i = (int)parameters[1];
string product_Name = parameters[2].ToString();
```

Comment: That's the same as all other answers. You *don't* need to wrap the values as `object` either, you can pass strongly-typed objects. In any case, BGW is obsolete. You can do the same things with `Task.Run` and `async/await` with the added benefit that you can chain multiple asynchronous operations

Answer (score -1):

we can always do with our custom list, please see below.

your custom class:

```
public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

List creation:

```
List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>()
{
   new Worker { Id = 1, Comments = "hello" }
};
```

Invoking background worker:

```
 backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(workers);
```

Reading your data:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Worker> workers = e.Argument as List<Worker>;
        //do your code here 
    }
```